# Why a simple query works in BIgquery but not PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, calculation

I wrote the query below to calculate the death percentage in Postgresql and the result is zero,but same query in Bigquery gets the correct result. Can anyone have idea? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
location,
MAX(total_cases) AS Cases_total,
MAX(total_deaths) AS Death_total, (MAX(total_deaths)/MAX(total_cases))*100 AS DeathPercentange
FROM covid_deaths
WHERE continent IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY DeathPercentange DESC;
```

I am not allowed to insert my screenshot so I have the link:

[Same query in Bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDn9v.png)

[Query in PostgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bckEZ.png)

The database looks like this:
[The preview of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRMap.png)

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this case? What does the source data look like? What is the expected output? What happens instead? Note that the restriction on inline images is probably to encourage you to put important details as text in the question; please click [edit] and do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is ok, your operation is between big integers. The result is just an integer.

```
112/9766 = 0 * 100 = 0
```

If you want a numeric as result you have to cast your columns as numeric

```
SELECT 
location,
MAX(total_cases) AS Cases_total,
MAX(total_deaths) AS Death_total, (MAX(total_deaths)::numeric/MAX(total_cases)::numeric)*100 AS DeathPercentange
FROM covid_deaths
WHERE continent IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY DeathPercentange DESC;
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You do integer division. The result will always be 0 whenever total_deaths < total_cases (which is most likely your case). What you should do is cast to float or decimal at least one operand, e.g.

```sql
(MAX(total_deaths)::decimal / MAX(total_cases))*100 AS DeathPercentange
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!